# Xcode Distribution provisional profile app validation issue

Tags: xcode5

I am trying to submit a new app to the app store. I have created a new Distribution profile and set the app ID to the new app's ID. I created the new app in iTunes. Now, when I attempt to validate the archive, on the top of the screen that prompts for the profile it displays the wrong app. Where does Xcode get this information from? What do I have set wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What does the app show in iTunes Connect? The status shoud be "Waiting for Upload". Also, check that you're using the same account on Xcode that you used on iTunes Connect (under Preferences - Accounts).

Answer (score 0):

if Xcode is bringing the wrong app, consider checking the app row in your iTunes connect.
make sure that the bundle id is the same as the archive name in Xcode.
hope it helped :)